# How can I interpolate html in the link function of an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Essentially I am trying to populate a table row as the accordion header in an Angular page:

```
   <div uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="deployment in deployments" is-open="deployment.isOpen">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        <status-Table deploy="{{deployment}}"></status-Table>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
   </div>
```

I cant seem to find a way to interpolate from the deployment object, once I pass it to the statusTable directive, and then populate the HTML using those vars:

```
app.directive('statusTable', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      deploy: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.html("<table class='table table-hover'>"+
                  "<tr>"+
                  "<td>{{ attrs.deploy.deployment_name }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ attrs.deply.region }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ attrs.deploy.start_date }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ attrs.deploy.deployment_date }}</td>"+
                  "<td><i class='material-icons 
green'>check_circle</i></td>"+
                  "</tr>"+
                  "</table>");
    }
  };
```

Comment: This is Angularjs (1.x) and not Angular ( 2+ )

Comment: @brijmcq yes, good sir. 1.6.2

Answer (score 1):

You should use '=' when including 'deploy' into your 'scope'.

```
scope: {
      deploy: '='
    }
```

'=' is for bi-directional binding. Change your html like this:

```
 <status-Table deploy="deployment"></status-Table>
```

Another way is to first pull the object into your link function:

```
if(attrs.deploy){
  scope.deploy = scope.$eval(attrs.deploy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Pass `deployment` by using `=`

2.Use `template` instead of `html`

```
<status-Table deploy="deployment"></status-Table>

app.directive('statusTable', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      deploy: '='
    },
    template: "<table class='table table-hover'>"+
                  "<tr>"+
                  "<td>{{ deploy.deployment_name }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ deploy.region }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ deploy.start_date }}</td>"+
                  "<td>{{ deploy.deployment_date }}</td>"+
                  "<td><i class='material-icons 
green'>check_circle</i></td>"+
                  "</tr>"+
                "</table>"
    }
  };
```